# How to open port 9000 on Windows 10 for Xdebug to work correctly?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, laravel-8

While testing in PhpStorm, I get the following error in the logs:

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9000 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port)
```

Here is my Xdebug config in php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = c:\localserver\php8.0.2\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.3-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll
xdebug.client_host=localhost
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.profiler_append=0
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_upon_error=yes
xdebug.output_dir="c:\localserver\php8.0.2\temp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name="cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

Windows брандмауэр выключен.

This error disappears when I configure XDebug to port 80

But still, I want to properly configure XDebug, for this I need to open port 9000. Please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling the project, everything worked by itself, but I still don't know what was the cause of the error. I believe that the reason was that I created the project before I installed PHPUnit globally and configured XDebug. Although of course I could be wrong.